# Jetpack Compose - A circle that flashes for 3 seconds, stops for 3 seconds. Repeatable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

So far I. have this -  how would I make it flash for 3 seconds stop for 3 seconds. Then repeat this until the composable is disposed.

```
@Composable
fun FlashingLight ( size: Dp , color: Color){
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()

    val lightFlashing by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0.0f,
        targetValue = 1.0f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(
                durationMillis = 500,
                delayMillis = 10,
                easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
        )
    )

    Canvas(modifier = Modifier
        .size(size),

        onDraw = {
            drawCircle(color = color.copy(alpha = lightFlashing))
        })
}
```

I tried this - unsuccessfully

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    repeat(3) {
    .........
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Kinda having a hard time understanding the final desired result. You want the circle to 'blink' for 3 seconds, then stay the same color for 3 then blink again? What exactly do u mean by 'flash'. What's the 0 and 1 here is what I'm asking

Comment: Hi Richard - apologies for the poor explanation. I basically need to duplicate a yellow light with these characteristics -   an intermittent flashing amber (yellow) beacon with a sequence of one flash per second for three (3) seconds followed by a three (3) second off-period.

Comment: So a circle that's yellow for three seconds then black for three then yellow for three again? Sorry for the late follow-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After slogging through the documentation - this works.

```
val lightFlashing by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
    initialValue = 0.0f,
    targetValue = 1.0f,
    animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
        animation = keyframes {
            durationMillis = 6000
            0.0f at 0 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            1.0f at 500 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            0.0f at 1000 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            1.0f at 1500 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            0.0f at 2000 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            1.0f at 2500 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            0.0f at 3000 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
            0.0f at 6000 with LinearOutSlowInEasing
        },
        repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart,
    )
)
```